Connecting aws glue with oracledb (using python-oracledb lib)
Summary:-
we are pulling data from a oracledb performing a few operations and finally writing it back to oracledb in aws glue.
While writing back to the oracledb we had to use the update statements for few tables.
So Glue supports direct insert into the table but it doesn't support update statements directly.
So we moved to pyhton-oracledb module so that we will be able to make changes to the dataframe and convert them  and use simple conditional statements to update the table.
Isssue:-
I tried using the normal thin mode but it was not supported so i had to go with thick mode
Made this glue script in which we have already placed the oracle-instant-client in an s3 bucket.I am pulling it into a tmp directory  and unzipping all the contents
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrameCollection
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
import oracledb as cx_Oracle

import os
import boto3
import subprocess
import platform

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket_name = 'mybucket'
object_key = 'path_To_My_Instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip'
local_file_path = '/tmp/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip'


s3.download_file(bucket_name, object_key, local_file_path) --copying the bucket to tmp dir

subprocess.run(['unzip', '/tmp/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip', '-d', '/tmp/instantclient'], check=True). --unzipping

print(platform.architecture())

os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/tmp/instantclient/instantclient_21_13' --setting up os path


cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir='/tmp/instantclient/instantclient_21_13'). --calling the lib

# Check if the directory exists
if os.path.isdir('/tmp/instantclient/instantclient_21_13'):
    print("Directory '/tmp/instantclient' exists")

# Check if the file exists
if os.path.isfile('/tmp/instantclient/instantclient_21_13/libnnz21.so'):
    print("File 'libnnz21.so:' exists")

# Check file permissions
print("File permissions:", oct(os.stat('/tmp/instantclient/instantclient_21_13/libnnz21.so').st_mode)[-3:])

Still i get this error telling the file not exist but when i check it by manually unzipping i am able to see the file

Error Category: RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR; DatabaseError: DPI-1047:
Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libnnz21.so: cannot
open shared object file: No such file or directory". See
https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html
for help

I got this link was a bit confusing
Unable to connect oracle database using cx_oracle from AWS Glue
Any idea would really help
Thank you in advance

On Linux, you cannot/should not pass lib_dir to init_oracle_client() with Oracle's supplied Instant Client (see all the doc).  The link you gave shows how to hack the libraries with patchelf to make it possible to do pass the param on Linux.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59467059/4799035 which shows how to run patchelf.
